# Cast performance from size_t to double

Tags: c, performance, casting

**TL;DR**: Why is multiplying/casting data in `size_t` slow and why does this vary per platform?

I'm having some performance issues that I don't fully understand. The context is a camera frame grabber where a 128x128 uint16_t image is read and post-processed at a rate of several 100 Hz.

In the post-processing I generate a histogram `frame->histo` which is of `uint32_t` and has `thismaxval` = 2^16 elements, basically I tally all intensity values. Using this histogram I calculate the sum and squared sum:

```c
double sum=0, sumsquared=0;
size_t thismaxval = 1 << 16;

for(size_t i = 0; i < thismaxval; i++) {
    sum += (double)i * frame->histo[i];
    sumsquared += (double)(i * i) * frame->histo[i];
}
```

Profiling the code with profile I got the following (samples, percentage, code):

```
 58228 32.1263 :  sum += (double)i * frame->histo[i];
116760 64.4204 :  sumsquared += (double)(i * i) * frame->histo[i];
```

or, the first line takes up 32% of CPU time, the second line 64%.

I did some benchmarking and it seems to be the datatype/casting that's problematic. When I change the code to

```
uint_fast64_t isum=0, isumsquared=0;

for(uint_fast32_t i = 0; i < thismaxval; i++) {
    isum += i * frame->histo[i];
    isumsquared += (i * i) * frame->histo[i];
}
```

it runs ~10x faster. However, this performance hit also varies per platform. On the workstation, a Core i7 CPU 950 @ 3.07GHz the code is 10x faster. On my Macbook8,1, which has a Intel Core i7 Sandy Bridge 2.7 GHz (2620M) the code is only 2x faster.

Now I am wondering:

1. Why is the original code so slow and easily sped up?
2. Why does this vary per platform so much?

**Update:**

I compiled the above code with

```
g++ -O3  -Wall cast_test.cc -o cast_test
```

**Update2:**

I ran the optimized codes through a profiler ([Instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqQBE.png) on Mac, like [Shark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXsKO.png)) and found two things:

1) The looping itself takes a considerable amount of time in some cases. `thismaxval` is of type `size_t`.

1. `for(size_t i = 0; i < thismaxval; i++)` takes 17% of my total runtime
2. `for(uint_fast32_t i = 0; i < thismaxval; i++)` takes 3.5%
3. `for(int i = 0; i < thismaxval; i++)` does not show up in the profiler, I assume it's less than 0.1%

2) The datatypes and casting matter as follows:

1. `sumsquared += (double)(i * i) * histo[i];` 15% (with `size_t i`)
2. `sumsquared += (double)(i * i) * histo[i];` 36% (with `uint_fast32_t i`)
3. `isumsquared += (i * i) * histo[i];` 13% (with `uint_fast32_t i`, `uint_fast64_t isumsquared`)
4. `isumsquared += (i * i) * histo[i];` 11% (with `int i`, `uint_fast64_t isumsquared`)

Surprisingly, `int` is faster than `uint_fast32_t`?

**Update4:**

I ran some more tests with different datatypes and different compilers, on one machine. The results are as follows.

For testd 0 -- 2 the relevant code is

```
    for(loop_t i = 0; i < thismaxval; i++)
        sumsquared += (double)(i * i) * histo[i];
```

with `sumsquared` a double, and `loop_t` `size_t`, `uint_fast32_t` and `int` for tests 0, 1 and 2.

For tests 3--5 the code is

```
    for(loop_t i = 0; i < thismaxval; i++)
        isumsquared += (i * i) * histo[i];
```

with `isumsquared` of type `uint_fast64_t` and `loop_t` again `size_t`, `uint_fast32_t` and `int` for tests 3, 4 and 5.

The compilers I used are gcc 4.2.1, gcc 4.4.7, gcc 4.6.3 and gcc 4.7.0. The timings are in percentages of total cpu time of the code, so they show relative performance, not absolute (although the runtime was quite constant at 21s). The cpu time is for both two lines, because I'm not quite sure if the profiler correctly separated the two lines of code.

```
gcc:    4.2.1  4.4.7  4.6.3  4.7.0
----------------------------------
test 0: 21.85  25.15  22.05  21.85
test 1: 21.9   25.05  22     22
test 2: 26.35  25.1   21.95  19.2
test 3: 7.15   8.35   18.55  19.95
test 4: 11.1   8.45   7.35   7.1
test 5: 7.1    7.8    6.9    7.05
```

or:

[image: casting performance]

Based on this, it seems that casting is expensive, regardless of what integer type I use.

Also, it seems gcc 4.6 and 4.7 are not able to optimize loop 3 (size_t and uint_fast64_t) properly.

Comment: could you also try it with `uint_fast32_t`? A wild guess is that it is faster due to the fact that the second datatype has the same bitlength as the machine instructions (64-bit). Guessing that you have a 64bit machine at least. I would expect that the fast32 is also slower. [edit] could you also test the size of both `uint_fast32_t` and `uint_fast64_t`? My guess is that the 32 is actually 64 bits.

Comment: Do you mean `uint_fast32_t isum`? I could try, although I think that could overflow, which is why I used uint_fast64_t.

Comment: Well, for 1.: Reason somehow dictates that casting ints to floats and doing float operations should be slower than doing int operations directly (although int-to-float shouldn't be as evil as float-to-int), even more so with the not that optimal x87 stack. Do you compile it with SSE support?

Comment: I made a small mistake in the previous comment, cant edit that anymore. Disregard that :). If you print the `sizeof(uint_fast32_t)`, my guess is that you will see 8 bytes. This means that it is the same size as a machine instruction, and it could be that this is faster to process.

Comment: @Yuri But as he said, it might overflow when used for the sum variables, as it only guarantees 32bit (even if on his system it's likely to be 64bit).

Comment: @ChristianRau now we have a different misunderstanding. I meant the variable `i`, which is actually declared as uint32. My guess was that the reason of the speedup had something to do with the size of `i`, but I can't reproduce it locally, so maybe it doesn't matter after all. It was just a wild guess :)

Comment: @Yuri Well yes, for `i` it's indeed a good idea to use `uint_fast32_t` and it may even be faster than a `size_t` (if that was only 32bit). Though, I think it was the more obvious switch from float oprations (together with casts) to direct int operations.

Comment: Can you post the disassembly?

Comment: I had an answer, but the assembly output from g++ 4.6.1 on Ubuntu is completely different from yours. So my answer is invalid and I deleted it. Can you post the timings that you get from running your code. Perhaps I can post a more relevant answer once I see those numbers.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like the difference is that I'm using GCC 4.6.1 and you're probably using 4.2. GCC is outputting much more optimized code in 4.6.1. So in that case I won't be able to answer your question since I don't have GCC 4.2.

Comment: Have you tried to use `double` for `i`? Then you don't have to cast the `i` every time. `double` should be large enough to store an 32-bit integer without losing precession. The increment, however, could be slower.

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot that you have then to cast `i` back to `int` because you are using it also in `histo[i]`. So probably a bad idea.

Comment: If you have a lot free time on your hands try running these tests with ICC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your original questions:

1. The code is slow because it involves the conversion from integer to
   float data types. That's why it's easily sped up when you use also
   an integer datatype for the sum-variables because it doesn't require
   a float-conversion anymore.
2. The difference is the result of several
   factors. For example it depends on how efficient a platform is able
   to perform an int->float conversion. Furthermore this conversion
   could also mess up processor-internal optimizations in the program
   flow and prediction engine, caches, ... and also the internal 
   parallelizing-features  of the processors can have a huge influence in 
   such calculations.

For the additional questions:

- "Surprisingly int is faster than uint_fast32_t"? What's the
  sizeof(size_t) and sizeof(int) on your platform? One guess I can make is, that both are 
  probably 64bit and therefore a cast to 32bit not only can give you
  calculation errors but also includes a different-size-casting
  penalty.

In general try to avoid visible and hidden casts as good as possible if these aren't really necessary. For example try to find out what real datatype is hidden behind "size_t" on your environment (gcc) and use that one for the loop-variable.
In your example the square of uint's cannot be a float datatype so it makes no sense to use double here. Stick to integer types to achieve maximum performance.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that casts are not ideal, but I didn't know it was so expensive. Regarding your second point: the machine is 64bit, but `uint_fast32_t` should be **at least** 32 bit if I understand it correctly, so if 64bit shouldn't it use that instead? I don't see why this explains that `int` is faster than `uint_fast32_t`. Also I don't see why the `for`-loop performance differs so much with different integer types.

Comment: Well, since `uint_fast32_t` should be the fastest integer type with at least 32 bits, the implementation should be smart enough to use a 64bit type if that is faster on a 64 bit system. But otherwise good answer, of course.

Comment: I ran some more tests and the bottom line is that casting is just expensive. I was surprised it was that expensive though.

Comment: the other difference between uint_fast32_t and int is signedness, I can't think of any intrinsic reason why that should matter but we're talking about how hard the compiler writer and chip designer have thought about making specific rare sequences go fast.

Comment: one thing you can do is maintain parallel loop counters, `double di = 0; for ( int i=0 ; i < thismaxval ; ++i,++di )`.

Answer (score 1):

On x86, the conversion of `uint64_t` to floating point is slower because there are only instructions to convert `int64_t`, `int32_t` and `int16_t`. `int16_t` and in 32-bit mode `int64_t` can only be converted using x87 instructions, not SSE.

When converting `uint64_t` to floating point, GCC 4.2.1 first converts the value as if it were an `int64_t` and then adds 2<sup>64</sup> if it was negative to compensate. (When using the x87, on Windows and *BSD or if you changed the precision control, beware that the conversion ignores precision control but the addition respects it.)

An `uint32_t` is first extended to `int64_t`.

When converting 64-bit integers in 32-bit mode on processors with certain 64-bit capabilities, a store-to-load forwarding issue may cause stalls. The 64-bit integer is written as two 32-bit values and read back as one 64-bit value. This can be very bad if the conversion is part of a long dependency chain (not in this case).