# What C++ type use for fastest "for cycles"?

Tags: c++, performance, types, for-loop

I think this is not answered on this site yet.

I made a code which goes through many combinations of 4 numbers. The number values are from 0 to 51, so they can be stored in 6 bits, so in 1 byte, am I right? I use these 4 numbers in nested for cycles and then use them in the lowest level for cycle. So what c++ type from those which can store at least 52 values is the fastest for iterating through 4 nested for cycles?

```
The code looks like: 
for(type first = 0; first != 49; ++first)
 for(type second = first+1; second != 50; ++second)
  for(type third = second+1; third != 51; ++third)
   for(type fourth = third+1; fourth != 52; ++fourth) {
    //using those values for about 1 bilion bit operations made in another for cycles 
   }
```

That code is very simplified and maybe there is also a better way for this kind of iterating, you can help me also with that.

Comment: I think `int` will be faster than `char`.

Comment: You mean you just change 4 bytes of an 32-bit int? I think your code uses 1 int for 4 loops. Space-optimized :)

Comment: I had [this problem as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596350/cast-performance-from-size-t-to-double) as a subset of a larger speed issue. For me `int` was faster than `uint_fast32_t` was faster than `size_t i`.

Comment: You'll get more speedup by doing more work per instruction, ala SIMD. Compiler *can* vectorize, in principle, but often you'll need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use the typedef `std::uint_fast8_t` from the header `<cstdint>`. It is supposed to be the "fastest" unsigned integer type with at least 8 bits.

Comment: I suspect this might give you the fastest 8 bit type, not the fastest overall. It is allowed to give a wider type, but will probably only do that if there are no 8 bit types at all.

Comment: @BoPersson: According to ISO/IEC 9899, it "designates an integer type that is usually fastest to operate with among _all_ integer types that have _at least_ the specified with."

Comment: Supposed to be, but it isn't, at least not on my computer. An `int` is far faster than is a `signed char`, yet `int_fast8_t` is typedefed as a `signed char` rather than as an `int`.

Comment: We also have to consider "usually fastest". If we have an array of  8 bit values, that might be faster than using `int` because of cache effects.

Comment: Please, don't consider cache effects, I will run it only once (only few times) and save the results to file.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest is whatever the underlying processor ALU can natively work with. Now registers may be addressable in multiple formats. In that case all those formats are equally fast.

So this becomes very processor architecture specific rather than C++ specific.
If you are working on a modern day PC processor then an int is as fast as anything else for your for loops.

On an embedded system there are more things to consider. Eg. Whether the variable is stored in an aligned location or not?

Answer (score 0):

On most machines, `int` is the fastest integer type. On all of the computers I work with, `int` is faster than `unsigned`, significantly faster than `signed char`.

Another issue, perhaps a bigger one, is what you are doing with those numbers. You didn't show the code, so there's no way of telling. Use `int` if you expect `first*second` to produce the expected integral value.

Yet another issue is how widely portable you expect this code to be. There's a huge distinction between code that will be ported to a number of different architectures, different compilers versus code that will be used in a limited and controlled setting. If it's the latter, write some benchmarks, and use the type under which the benchmarks perform best. The problem is a bit tougher if you are writing something for wide consumption.